# Ruby set dictionary for search with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app i'm fetching data from mysql database, part of code:

```
@search = ArtLookup.find(:all, :conditions => ['MATCH (ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) and ARL_KIND = 1', search_condition.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')])
```

But main trouble that i have different suppliers price list's, and there i have different coding's for same variable in db, for example:

```
LEMFÖRDER
```

But how can i set dictionary for my `search_condition` so that if my `search_condition` is for example:

```
LEM?FORDER or
LEMFOERDER or
LEMFÖRDER
```

It will find my `LEMFÖRDER` in db?

I know that it could sound very strange, sorry for my english, but i explain all on my example...

Comment: I would say you should think about using sphinx or solr, or about calculating levinstein distance for your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using ActiveRecord's [AREL](https://github.com/rails/arel) engine like the following:

```
def lookup(*alternatives)
  match_condition = 'MATCH (ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)'

  or_conditions = alternatives.map do |alternative|
    ArtLookup.where(match_condition, alternative).
    where_values.reduce(:and)
  end

  and_condition = ArtLookup.where('ARL_KIND = 1').where_values.reduce(:and)

  # Build a disjunction
  conditions = or_conditions.shift

  or_conditions.each do |condition|
    conditions = conditions.or(condition)
  end

  # Build the final conjunction
  conditions = conditions.and(and_condition)

  ArtLookup.where(conditions)
end
```

Then you can find the objects like the following:

```
@search = lookup('LEM?FORDER', 'LEMFOERDER', 'LEMFÖRDER')
```

Or directly provide an array:

```
alternatives = [
  'LEM?FORDER',
  'LEMFOERDER',
  'LEMFÖRDER'
]

@search = lookup(*alternatives)
```

I'm aware of the fact that this is far too much code for the simple thing it's doing. But it should do it and I'm not aware of a much better way. I didn't test that code, so it could contain some minor mistakes.

Comment: but what to do if i don't have lemforder in query? but for example brembo? I must check for example for LEMF and if string has it, than do you code...

Comment: Simply make a method out of it with `alternatives` as an argument. See my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, in this case, you should start using a library to deal with full-text-search and additional search capabilities, like Solr or Sphinx.

Take a look at http://pat.github.com/ts/en/searching.html.

This kind of complexity is common and it is already implemented in many algorithms.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

*If I've understood your question correctly*, you want to have Mysql treat those three values as the same thing. Now, assuming that they are considered the same thing in a specific language (for example, ß = ss in German), Mysql will handle this automatically based on your [collation settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html), so selecting the correct collation should fix it for you.

Comment: no... collation must be such as i have now... in db i didn't have any ß etc... Only normal English... But i must tell ruby that if he see LEM?FORDER or
LEMFOERDER or
LEMFÖRDER it compare bd's LEMFORDER, so i need something like hash